Styles from an scss file are applied to an element, but not the child elements of it
This probably has something to do with Angular Material Chips, but I can't figure out how or why.
The actual thing I'm trying to accomplish is different, but here's an illustration. Style gets applied to the mat-chip-row element:

However for the child element, the scss file doesn't even appear anywhere in the style list:
The scss currently looks like this:

.message-reaction {
  & .mdc-evolution-chip-set .mdc-evolution-chip {
    margin: 2px;
    height: 28px;

    & span {
      padding-left: 0px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}

I've tried many variations - no style ever gets applied to any descendant element of mat-chip-row. It doesn't get overridden, it just never appears in the style list. I can edit the styles for those elements in devtools and those are applied. I tried copying the selectors of those elements into the scss - just doesn't get applied. It doesn't seem to be a selector problem. For some reason the file just stops mattering for anything below mat-chip-row.

The span is created/generated outside the component, so the CSS in a component is normally scoped to inside the component.
So you need the css defined to be visible outside the component, you can use ng-deep for this.
::ng-deep .message-reaction {
  & .mdc-evolution-chip-set .mdc-evolution-chip {
    margin: 2px;
    height: 28px;

    & span {
      padding-left: 0px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}


Good answer, but note that ng-deep should be avoided and you should instead use a global style with a custom selector

@MGX I got another comment a while ago saying you can do it simply using ng-deep when I suggested your method, i leave it to the original poster to decide their preference

no problem, as I said it's a good answer, I too use it myself, but it's good to know that it is to be avoided !

For more information : https://angular.dev/guide/components/styling#ng-deep

Thanks for answer and comments. Going with the ng-deep appears to be the only way I can actually keep the css next to the component in my code.
I am writing a message-reaction component that uses the chips and linking the css through styleUrls property of the component.
I feel like css that applies only to this component should stay with the component.
It's so weird that using chips inside a component results in them not being part of the component and requires a global style. Feels like I'm still doing something wrong on that part.

Since "The Angular team strongly discourages new use of ::ng-deep." you should try to

(A) keep all HTML elements of a component within a components "DOM branch".
In PrimeNG you are able to achieve this by letting the appendTo parameter empty. On Angular Material I can't tell and haven't found something like that.

If that's not possible in your case, you should

(B) put the css-code within your global css-file like (@MGX mentioned first) this:
/styles.css
.message-reaction {
  & .mdc-evolution-chip-set .mdc-evolution-chip {
    margin: 2px;
    height: 28px;

    & span {
      padding-left: 0px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  }
}


And if you really want to

(C) stick to ::ng-deep, then you should keep in mind, it's already deprecated, which basically means, your code can break anytime by an angular update.

How is the span not in the DOM branch of the component though? Its parent is in the branch, but the span itself isn't? I don't understand.

I'm not 100% sure, because I don't have experience with Angular Material. But I assume it also puts "their" components outside of "your" component. That's the way PrimeNG does it in some cases. For better understanding what I mean I provide you this professional made illustration: https://i.imgur.com/KZVmmHA.png
